# How do I validate a user's input and make sure it is the correct type and within a given range?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, validation

I'm trying to write a program that will help me in my job to write behavioral reports on teenage boys in a therapeutic program. The goal is to make it easier to write the everyday expectations(eating, hygiene, school attendance, etc) so that I can write the unique behaviors and finish the report faster. I'm currently working on how many meals the boy at during the day and am trying to get it to validate that the user input is the correct type of input and within the correct range(0-3). Afterwards I want to change the variable depending on the answer given so it will print a string stating how many meals they ate. I've been able to get the program to validate the type to make sure that the user gave and integer but I cant get it to make sure that the given answer was in the desired range. Any help would be appreciated I only started learning python and programming a month ago so very inexperienced.
Here's what my code looks like so far and what I would like the variable to change to depending on the given answer.

```
Name=input('Student Name:')

while True:
    try:
        Meals=int(input('Number of Meals(between 0-3):'))
    except ValueError:
            print ('Sorry your response must be a value between 0-3')
            continue
    else:
        break

    while True:
        if 0<= Meals <=3:
            break
        print('not an appropriate choice please select a number between 0-3')
        #if Meals== 3:
        #Meals= 'ate all 3 meals today'
        #elif Meals==2:
        #Meals='ate 2 meals today'
        #elif Meals==1:
        #Meals='ate only 1 meal today'
        #elif Meals==0:
        #Meals='did not eat any meals today'
```

Comment: What did you intend your code to do by writing `else: break`?

Comment: Honeslty I don't know. I was googling how to do this and found something similar that had the  else: break  and figured it was needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if number of inputted meals falls to valid range and if yes, break from the loop. If not, raise an Exception:

```
while True:
    try:
        meals = int(input('Number of Meals(between 0-3):'))
        if 0 <= meals <= 3:
            break
        raise Exception()
    except:
        print('Please input valid integer (0-3)')


print('Your choice was:', meals)
```

Prints (for example):

```
Number of Meals(between 0-3):xxx
Please input valid integer (0-3)
Number of Meals(between 0-3):7
Please input valid integer (0-3)
Number of Meals(between 0-3):2
Your choice was: 2
```